# Standard ListView with swipe feature

Tags: wpf, listview, swipe, gestures

I'm trying to add swipe action to a standard WPF listview, but all I could find was support for swiping on UWP.

Do you know of any framework implementations or 3rd party libraries that support this feature?

Comment: What is your correct requirement?  any screenshot?

Comment: Just a normal swipe left or right like done in android

Comment: You can use standard View Pager.

Comment: I need a swiping feature for a listview, not for paging